# switching desktop from Windows 10 to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10

Right now my desktop is acting as a do everything kind of ok rig. Some light gaming. Media server. Linux distro downloader. Normal Internet usage.

One of the big things holding me back from the switch is how my drives are set up. Current running a drive pool that is powered by StableBit. With a couple folders (user folders) being mirrored.

So with that being said. Is there a way I can set something like that up in Ubuntu? The Linux file system is something that I know the least about.

I have been playing around with Ubuntu off and on for years now. Just feel like it's time to dive into this or get window 10 pro.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `Current running a drive pool that is powered by StableBit. With a couple folders (user folders) being mirrored.`?

Comment: `I have been playing around with Ubuntu off and on for years now.` - Did you try Ubuntu on that machine? Does something not work?

Comment: I been using it in a virtual machine and it works good.

Comment: It looks like StableBit is some sort of dodgy RAID solution. I would recommend learning how to do software RAID in Linux. You have many options for this. You can use ZFS, LVM with mdraid, BTRFS, etc.